How to connect my backend-service using frontend service in minikube
So, the scenario is, I have created two service one is frontend service and another is backend service.
In my frontend angular application i have given the url like
http://192.168.1.5:32000/busyBox/api/v1/tasks
so, the given ip 192.168.1.5 is the minikube ip and 32000 is the nodePort
and i have hardcoded this url in the frontend, which is not the actual problem.
My actual problem is whenever i restart my minikube , my ip changes and then i have to make changes in the url and then get the image again and again.
Is there any way, i can set a url and i do not have to change again to connect to my backend service?
I have given both the deployment and service yml for both
backend
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: busybox-backend-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: busybox-backend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: busybox-backend

    spec:
      containers:
        - name: busybox-backend
          image: jahedulislam/busybox-backend:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080

          env:
            - name: DB_HOST
              value: mysql
            - name: DB_NAME
              value: busyBox
            - name: DB_USERNAME
              value: root
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              value: root

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: busybox-backend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: busybox-backend
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: "TCP"
      nodePort: 32500
  type: NodePort

frontend
apiVersion: apps/v1 # Kubernetes API version
kind: Deployment # Kubernetes resource kind we are creating
metadata:
  name: frontend-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: angular
  replicas: 1 # Number of replicas that will be created for this deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: angular
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: angular
          image: jahedulislam/busybox-frontend:latest # Image that will be used to containers in the cluster
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80 # The port that the container is running on in the cluster

---
kind: Service # Kubernetes resource kind we are creating
apiVersion: v1 # Kubernetes API version
metadata:
  name: frontend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: angular
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31000
  type: NodePort


ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: busybox-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: busybox.local
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /busyBox/api/v1
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: busybox-backend-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend-service
                port:
                  number: 80


Can you add Ingress resources for the two components, and use those to access the application?  Then the two components will be on the same hostname and port, and you should be able to use a path-only URL to access them.  That would let you get rid of the hard-coded IP and port.

@DavidMaze Seems like it does not work or i have done something wrong, I have updated the description with the ingress.yaml. Can you please have a look?

If you already have that Ingress setup, set your application to call just the path /busyBox/api/v1/...; don't include a host name or port in the URL.  This will resolve to the host name and port of the current page, which should be coming via the same Ingress path.

Thanks for your response.
In the URl i have used only http://busyBox/api/v1 from my frontend side.
and then when i hit http://busybox.local it gives me the frontend view however when i click those buttons it does call the api with this path http://busybox/api/v1/tasks -- Note: It does call the api with /busybox the box starting with the lowercase letter.

If you would like to connect to backend service from frontend app I think best option is to use internal kubernetes network and not exposing your backend via ingress.
DNS setup is described in documentation but what you can use as URL is following line http://busybox-backend-service.<<namespace name>>.svc.cluster.local:8080/busyBox/api/v1/tasks.
With that please change you backend service type to ClusterIP.

The question mentions an Angular application.  If the client is actually running in an end user's browser, it can't see the ...cluster.local DNS names or reach a ClusterIP-type Service; it must use an Ingress or one of the externally-accessible Service types.

If I understand correctly frontend need to communicate with backend application. Currently it is communicating via ingress which is not the best way of connecting two apps in the same cluster. Due to that my proposition is to use internal k8s network since service and namespace will not change each time when cluster is bring up.

...but if the "frontend" is a browser-based application, it's not actually running in the cluster.

From manifests that @Jahedul Islam posted I can see that both frontend and backend applications are running in k8s cluster. What I understand is that URL http://192.168.1.5:32000/busyBox/api/v1/tasks is currently hardcoded in frontend image which is problematic since minikube IP is changing. To fix this problem my proposal is to use internal k8s communication via service so starting cluster would not require rebuilding frontend image.

@MichałLewndowski I have tried your approach and it shows an error like "NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST"
I have also changed this to clusterIp

@DavidMaze if i use localhost:8080/busybox/api/v1/ will this not work as my port and targetPort both are defined as 8080. I have tried this one as well, it does not get connected as well. Is it supposed to?

Could you provide URL that you added to frontend application and tell in which namespace you deployed backend app with k8s service?

Sorry for the delay @MichałLewndowski, my url in frontend app 'http://busybox-backend-service.default.svc.cluster.local:8080/busyBox/api/v1/tasks', deployed in minikube default namespace and bend service has clusterIP

the error in network tab ->
tasks                   failed)net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED xhr polyfills-A7MJM4D4.js:1 0 B 2.80 s tasks (failed)net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RES

Are you able to reach http://busybox-backend-service.default.svc.cluster.local:8080/busyBox/... URL when you sh to frontend pod?

Okay the way i have resolved it.
Option 1: I just have set the url to localhost:8080 the port that is pointing to my backend pod and i have port-forwarded both of backend and frontend pod to the desired port respectively 4200 and 8080. And then hitting the localhost:4200 it works just like the local development.
Option 2: For this one i have used traefik ingress controller and then i have set the url to just /busyBox/api/v1 and i have configured the rules in the traefik like this (Ignore the certificate related things) which says that any incoming traffic coming to this /busyBox endpoint redirect them to my backend service.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: busybox-ingress
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "selfsigned-issuer" # Ensure this matches your actual issuer
spec:
  ingressClassName: traefik
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - my.busybox.space
        - prod.busybox.space
      secretName: busybox-tls-secret # Ensure this secret is created and contains the TLS certificate
  rules:
    - host: my.busybox.space
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /busyBox
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: busybox-backend-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend-service
                port:
                  number: 80
    - host: prod.busybox.space
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /busyBox
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: busybox-backend-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend-service
                port:
                  number: 80

